# Can't get shared filters in home view to work in spree demo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, demo

In the spree demo (latest version), I tried to use shared/filters instead of shared/taxonomies in views/spree/home/index.html.erb:

```
<% content_for :sidebar do %>
  <div data-hook="homepage_sidebar_navigation">
    <%#= render :partial => 'spree/shared/taxonomies' %>
    <%= render :partial => 'spree/shared/filters' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I get the filters (All Taxons), but when I pick some, like Bags and T-Shirts and click on search, the filter doesn't work.

I didn't change anything in shared/filters:

```
<% filters = @taxon ? @taxon.applicable_filters : [Spree::Core::ProductFilters.all_taxons] %>
<% unless filters.empty? %>
  <%= form_tag '', :method => :get, :id => 'sidebar_products_search' do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'per_page', params[:per_page] %>
    <% filters.each do |filter| %>
      <% labels = filter[:labels] || filter[:conds].map {|m,c| [m,m]} %>
      <% next if labels.empty? %>
      <div class="navigation" data-hook="navigation">
        <h6 class="filter-title"> <%= filter[:name] %> </h6>
        <ul class="filter_choices">
          <% labels.each do |nm,val| %>
            <% label = "#{filter[:name]}_#{nm}".gsub(/\s+/,'_') %>
            <li class="nowrap">
              <input type="checkbox"
                     id="<%= label %>"
                     name="search[<%= filter[:scope].to_s %>][]"
                     value="<%= val %>"
                     <%= params[:search] && params[:search][filter[:scope]] && params[:search][filter[:scope]].include?(val.to_s) ? "checked" : "" %> />
              <label class="nowrap" for="<%= label %>"> <%= nm %> </label>
            </li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= submit_tag Spree.t(:search), :name => nil %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Did you check the code in your `spree/shared/filters` partial? Can you post that code, too if you think it is correct and still not working?

Comment: I didn't make any changes there, see edit

Comment: So when you say it doesn't work, you mean it doesn't redirect you to search page? or throw errors?

Comment: home/index is called, but the listed products are not filtered